# Micro USB splitting cable that allows charging and reads standard USB simultaneously (Samsung Tab S2)

Tags: usb, android, tablet, splitters

I recently bought the Galaxy Tab S2, 9.7" (T813; Android Marshmallow) thinking I could simultaneously charge it and read files from a standard USB drive using a cable such as one found [here](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CXAC1ZW/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_12?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2086U0HXZJZIA).

However, once I got my tablet and went to buy the above cable, I saw in the comments that it does *not* charge the tablet (the female micro USB extension must just *read* micro USB drives). I've looked at countless cables like the one above, and all of them say the same thing in the comments - they do *not* charge the tablet (parent device).

For work, I keep my files on a standard USB, as I use multiple devices on a given day and need to be able to access my files on all of them (cloud isn't an option for me for various reasons, so please do not recommend that as a solution). Thus, there will be instances where I'll need to charge my tablet and simultaneously read files from a USB drive.

Basically, I need a cord that *looks* exactly like the one at the above link, but **where the female micro USB port actually charges the tablet (parent device) when the micro USB charging cable is plugged into it** (and obviously the female standard USB reads files from my USB drive).

**Does anyone know of a cable that achieves these two things?**

*I've already explored this issue via:*

1. Samsung customer service (*multiple times to see if I could get different answers*)
2. Samsung community forum (*no responses to-date*)
3. Reading Amazon product descriptions and reviews
4. Asking other Amazon customers (*no knowledge of such a product*)
5. Asking Best Buy employees (*didn't know cables wouldn't charge*)
6. Internet searches
7. Facebook crowdsourcing (*no responses*)
8. Asking a family member who works in IT (*not aware of any such product*)
9. Android Enthusiasts StackExchange (*question on hold as possibly irrelevant on that forum; recommended I try here*)

After all of this, I've come up with nothing and am running out of resources. Please help (begging/desperate/etc.). I need to figure out if this tablet will work for me or if I need to return it.

Comment: @Jeff: I would appreciate it if you could explain why is this not a recommendation for hardware for a specific task. I need a cable that charges the parent device and allows me to read a USB drive simultaneously - that is the task I need to achieve. I would like to know if hardware exists to support this task. This question is not specific to my device - many devices are moving to a single micro USB (or other single port). I figured if I *didn't* say what device I was using, someone would inevitably ask anyway.

Comment: will that work for you scenario?

Comment: @Jeff: I will look at it in more detail when I get a second and let you know. It's not immediately clear to me how I would use the device you link to below, so I have to look more at its capabilities. Thank you for your time on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52024/discussion-between-jeff-and-meg).

Comment: @Jeff I don't see this as a tech support question; the OP is looking for a secondary device that supports a set of features, which is what this site was made for. The only thing that might be an issue is that the requested hardware is a cable, and I am not sure if cables are on-topic [here](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/266/60).

Comment: @Cfinley Thanks for the input I was waiting for someone to chime in.  I have retracted the flag and deleted my comment regarding such.  And hopefully i answered this accordingly for her.

Answer (score 1):

I did quite a bit of research on this issue and it seems that all the cables that you are looking at tend to be unreliable / don't work / only provide 1000ma.

There are additional options that include rooting your device.

After coming to the conclusion that they were not "GOOD" options I found the following.

[RavPower Filehub @ Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L9TEIMW)

This product has good reviews and will allow you to bridge your tablet to a wired or wireless network.  Additionally you get the convenience of being able to to use Micro SD cards as well.

While there are other options there is not guarantee that they will work and this is the only full proof solution I could find for you.

EDITS: (To explain functionality of device)

You DO NOT need to root your device for this to work as mentioned about other devices in the comments above.

This device is a wireless / network bridge.  Effectively you would connect this device to you existing wired / wireless network and it will create a secondary wireless network for your tablet to connect to.

You can plug your USB or SD Card into the device (Or even a USB hard drive) and then you can access the files on them through either a web browser by connecting to the ip address of the RavPower Filehub or by using the FileHub app that can be downloaded on your tablet. [Link to Product Manual](https://www.ravpower.com/support/product/manual/view/MTEz)

As far as charging your device too it only provides 1 amp of power so some devices will not charge.  That being said the port on the tablet will not be used so you can easily plug in your power cord.

2nd EDIT:

The product is only 2.9 inches x 2.7 inches x .9 inches so it is very portable.

Comment: Thank you for finding this product for me! Let me know if I'm understanding correctly: Since it's a power bank and has a USB port, if I were low on battery I could plug-in to this and charge and read my USB at the same time. Is that what you were thinking? I like that it can also read micro SD cards - will come in handy since I have expansion cards in two devices. I'm not sure about rooting my device - I've not done it before, and am not sure what I would need to do in order to ultimately accomplish the goal, but if someone could give instructions, I would consider it.

Comment: @Meg I have updated the answer to include  more details regard use as well as the product manual.  If you requirements in your question were correct this device will free up your port on your tablet completely so you can plug it into a charger and this device will act as a wireless file hub for you and accomplish your task.

Comment: Ah, I see (I did understand I don't have to root my device for this option - my previous comment was just about rooting in general, with regard to other possible solutions). So it's a wireless way to access a USB, micro SD card, etc. Have you used anything like this, and, if so, could you comment on what it's like using a browser/FileHub app to access files? Can I edit them in-place on my USB, or do I need to download them, save them, edit them, then re-save them to my USB? My other hesitation is a cable is so much easier to carry around/travel with... Just can't have it all I guess!

Comment: I have added the size to the answer.  Looking at the manual it does not seem like there is any issue with edit in place.  I have used this same scenario in my router that allows me to add storage and editing in place is no issue.  If you buy the product from Amazon it is easy to return :)  I will say that some of this is starting to turn into tech support.  So we might want to move this to SU for more support related questions but I think we have covered everything I know about this device.  I can tell you I am ordering one for my network here since it basically doubles as a wifi extender.

Comment: I guess this has sort of turned into tech support, but I feel it's relevant to be able to answer the question - whether the suggested product is a realistic solution. I did look at the device's size and you're correct that it's small relatively speaking, but I'm just thinking about my daily commute and things start adding up when you have a tablet, phone, power banks, this device and chargers (and possibly a laptop and its charger, depending on the day) ;) Such is technology. I do think this is a good option though, and am likely going to order it. Your help has been invaluable! Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to leave the solution unchecked at the moment, just in case anything else trickles in. I doubt there is a cable that does what I need, or we probably would have had someone post about it by now. I'll give it some time and see how things play out. I really do appreciate your help.